# index.html is unable to read from CSS after FTP to server

Tags: html, css, ftp

I have my website which consists of two pages, plus my own style.css that works perfectly on my local. But when I FTP it onto the server of my hosting service, the index.html is unable to read from my style.css. I've checked the path. I've checked the order of declaration. I've maintained the same file structure and the same order of CSS declaration (global to local)on my local, and its working fine. Does anyone have suggestions?

Here is how the head section looks:

I had to declare a CSS style for a script I'm using in the document. Since it won't read my style.css I did an internal declaration.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Google Font: Source Code Pro-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Fancybox CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

<!-- My CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fancybox jQuery -->
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>



<style type="text/css">

.menuActive {

    background-color: #ffffff;

}

</style>
</head>
```

A relevant portion of my file structure on the server is as follows (tried including a screenshot but apparently I can't do that on Stackoverflow just yet):

Folders & files:
css
fancybox
files
img
wp_admin
wp-content
wp-includes
.ftpquota
.htaccess
default.htm
index.html

The img folder is on the same level as the css folder and the images are loading properly.

Comment: Clear your cache? Any errors in the console? How about posting your code in your question?

Comment: Can you post your link tag

Comment: @j08691 posted my code.

Comment: @Adam the <link> for my style sheet appears as above.

Comment: can u please give us a snippet of your file structure from the server? EDIT: I mean a snip, screenshot or equivalent...

Comment: open the page in your browser, copy and paste the rendered css link and paste it into the url box - if it 404s you're css file is wrongly called

Comment: @Olof Just updated my post to include file structure info

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs What page are you asking me to open in the browser and which CSS link are you asking me to copy paste?

Comment: @Bhuvana your page that references your css.. and the css link to your stylesheet that the browser has

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I just did that and it is able to open my style.css.

Comment: then inspect the element - see if the css is being overriden by anything else (it will have a grey line through it if the case)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Just did that. No grey line through it.

Comment: @Bhuvana interesting - try using the full path for the link to the css file - if it still doesn't work then maybe contact your hosting providers and see if they have any funky permissions on their server

Answer (score 0):

It's probally because on your server you are using `https://`
change your style links to something like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>` and remove http part

Comment: Thank you. But my style.css has no http:// or https://. It's in the same location as my index.html!

Comment: you have google fonts and externals styles, you should change it and see how it goes